# Year() function in BindingSource.Filter property

Tags: c#

I have a DataGrid that is bound to a DataTable with a BindingSource. In my DataTable, there is a DateTime field that is used to record payment history for many years. I am unable to filter my list(DataGrid) using the BindingSource.Filter property which gives me only a result of payment in year 2010.

```
paymentBindingSource.Filter = "Year(PaymentDate)='2010'";
```

Then i got an error. 'The expression contains undefined function call Year().'
Anyone has any ideas?

Comment: Try: `'' + yourdatecolumn LIKE '*2010*'

Answer (score 0):

The filter property must follow the syntax defined [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression.aspx) as far as i can see there is no `Year()` function, hence the error.  I would suggest you add an extra column to your data source that contains the value of the year of the payment date and then filter on that column.

Comment: So, it means that this is the only way. Thanks a lot.